# Integrate user specific kibana dashboard in react web app

Tags: reactjs, kibana

I am currently working on integrating kibana dashboard into my react application.

Here is my useCase:

Each user has their own data with same structure, the dashboard (visualizations would be same, but the data in the charts would be specific to the user).

How do i load the data into dashboard user specific from react app?

Is it better to create a dashboard in kibana and embed it into react application using iframe.

If yes, Then how do i pass the user id to the backend service / elastic search which kibana uses from my react application ?

or

Is there any way we can pass the authorization token from the react app to kibana (elastic search / backend api). Such that, kibana dashboard loads the data by user specific..

or

Can i use the chart plugins which kibana uses currently in their dashboard and use them (integrate kibana chart plugins in react application)pass the data to those chart plugins to visualize the charts .
refer 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/known-plugins.html

If No,  Is there any alternative mechanism ?

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: You should generally make an attempt at what you're trying to accomplish and post what you've tried before asking

Comment: Thanks @ChrI .. I have created a kibana dashboard and i have embedded into my react application. But, i am researching on how to pass the user id (custom parameters from my react app. so that, kibana dashboards loads the data with specific user id.

Comment: @VishalKumar do you figuere it out?